# Calculate the number of trips in graph traversal

Tags: graph, dynamic-programming, bellman-ford

Hello Stack Overflow Community,

I'm attempting to solve this problem:
https://uva.onlinejudge.org/index.php?option=com_onlinejudge&Itemid=8&page=show_problem&problem=1040

The problem is to find the best path based on capacity between edges. I get that this can be solved using Dynamic Programming, I'm confused by the example they provide:

[image: Map]

According to the problem description, if someone is trying to get 99 people from  city 1 to 7, the route should be 1-2-4-7 which I get since the weight of each edge represents the maximum amount of passengers that can go at once. What I don't get is that the description says that it takes at least 5 trips. Where does the 5 come from? 1-2-4-7 is 3 hops, If I take this trip I calculate 4 trips, since 25 is the most limited hop in the route, I would say you need 99/25 or at least 4 trips. Is this a typo, or am I missing something?

Comment: The only thing I could think of that would make this example correct is that he should be available with the tourists on each trip so he can only transport 24 passengers each trip.

Comment: yeah, that must be it. Have to count the guide.

Comment: By the way, that was it. Looking on back on this question, it should have been obvious. Thank you Stackoverflow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given the first line of the problem statement:

> Mr. G. works as a tourist guide.

It is likely that Mr. G must always be present on the bus, thus the equation for the number of trips is:

```
x = (ceil(x) + number_of_passengers) / best_route
```

rather than simply:

```
x = number_of_passengers / best_route
```

or, for your numbers:

```
x = (ceil(x) + 99) / 25
```

Which can be solved with:

```
x == 4.16 (trips)
```